# Is it possible to circumvent the port-forwarding requirements for GFWL?

Tags: networking, games-for-windows-live

We're trying to play Dead Rising 2 on the same LAN, only to learn that Games for Windows Live expects you to forward 4 ports from your firewall to the PC.  Obviously this isn't going to work in our situation.  Has anyone found a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a couple hours of additional net-scouring, we tried a lot of suggestions, and when it finally worked, of course we'd changed a few things.  So, in our case the solution was one or all of the following:

- Move the GFWL-required ports from port-forwarding (on the router) to port-triggering
- Disable all non-related (virtual) NIC adapters (in our case, they were for VMWare & VirtualBox)
- Make sure the firewall exception for DR2 is present in Windows Firewall

My money is on the port-triggering.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with the solution, and sorry we couldn't be of more help =^)

Comment: No worries, I was VERY motivated to figure it out.  There was zombie-stomping at stake!

Comment: I'd also try placing the PCs in the DMZ, which is the most comfortable solution, but also the riskiest.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to change registry values:
[Games fow Windows Live Support](http://www.microsoft.com/games/en-us/support/pages/troubleshootingissues.aspx)

Look all the way down at the bottom at the **Port Override** section.  Exact instruction are as follows:

1. Open your registry in the Windows registry editor.
2. Navigate to the following registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Software\Microsoft\XLive
3. Add a new DWORD value. Enter LivePortOverride as the name and the new port number as the value. This value must be greater than 5000 and less than 65535.