# How do I play GFWL online with multiple computers on the LAN?

Tags: games-for-windows-live

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to circumvent the port-forwarding requirements for GFWL?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8169/is-it-possible-to-circumvent-the-port-forwarding-requirements-for-gfwl)

According to GFWL, you need to forward various ports (like port 80) in order to play online; this is especially true for Dark Souls. The full list of ports are here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937424

Now say I have 2 PCs on the same network who want to play the same GFWL game.

How can I play online when it requires those ports forwarded for each PC? Looking at the port forward settings, you can only enter 1 LAN IP but you need both those PCs to have those ports open for GFWL.

How can this be accomplished?